# Finding word occurrences in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var temp = "This is a string.";
var findtext="is";
var count = (temp.match("/"+findtext+"/g") || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

I have made a java script function which gets the user string from a text area. It take another perimeter for the word which is to be found from the entered text. It gives me error as I am not able to get the number of occurrence for the word to be found from the string.

Comment: You don't need the `/.../g`. Try just `(temp.match(findtext) || []).length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), and a word boundary to match whole words so as to not match the `is` in `This` etc

```js
var temp     = "This is a string.";
var findtext = "is";
var regex    = new RegExp('\\b'+ findtext+'\\b', 'g');
var count    = (temp.match(regex) || []).length;

console.log(count);
```

Comment: well heres my code i have plugged in your response but javascript shows no response.

Comment: function determine()
    {
            var keytext=document.getElementById('fn').value;
            var Ctext=document.getElementById('ta').value;
            alert(Ctext +" :::: "+ keytext);          
         
            
          
            var regex    = new RegExp('\\b'+ keytext+'\\b', 'g');
            var count    = (Ctext.match(regex) || []).length;

            alert("your count is : "count);
        
    }